# How to remove the "Source:" from this Tumblr theme?

Tags: html, css, themes, tumblr

I am trying to edit the Tumblr theme below so as to remove the "Source:" portion that appears at the bottom of every post I reblog.

I don't mind giving credit where credit is due, but this information is already visible in the Tumblr app and on the permalinks of each post... I just want it to not clutter the homepage.

Here's [an example](http://example-stackoverflow.tumblr.com) of how a reblog currently looks.

And here's [the code](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=fSHDRhhc) of the theme I'm currently using.

I've tried editing the code to make the "Source" line disappear, but to no avail. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is being added from a javascript include, perhaps. I don't see anything in the source code on your Example blog or in the template that would include that. Try the solution found [here](http://ettudis.tumblr.com/post/25799638579/how-to-remove-source-link-on-tumblr):

> Some themes do not include the source link codes which makes “via/source” links automatically appear under posts (such as quotes or text). To remove those, insert the following between {block:posts} and {/block:posts}

```
{block:ContentSource}
<!-- {SourceURL}{block:SourceLogo}<img src="{BlackLogoURL}"
width="{LogoWidth}" height="{LogoHeight}" alt="{SourceTitle}" />  
{/block:SourceLogo}
{block:NoSourceLogo}{SourceLink}{/block:NoSourceLogo} -->
{/block:ContentSource}
```

> What you’re doing is hiding the codes so that it ONLY appears in the CODES (are not displayed unless you search up HTML) since you’re adding  around the codes which makes it a “comment”. It’s still read, but it’s hidden and only visible in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the "source" and also the "via" paste this code below the "{/block:posts}"

```
{block:ContentSource}
<!-- {SourceURL}{block:SourceLogo}<img src="{BlackLogoURL}"
width="{LogoWidth}" height="{LogoHeight}" alt="{SourceTitle}" />
{/block:SourceLogo}
{block:NoSourceLogo}{SourceLink}{/block:NoSourceLogo} -->
{/block:ContentSource}

<!--{block:NoRebloggedFrom}{block:RebloggedFrom}{ReblogParentName}{/block:RebloggedFrom}{/block:NoRebloggedFrom} -->
```

Answer (score -1):

You can remove those paragraphs generated by Tumblr using jQuery's .remove() function.

http://api.jquery.com/remove/

```
$("p").remove(":contains('Source:'),:contains('via ')");
```

Comment: If you happen to use “via” in your post, it will be gone.