# Remove default "Source:" from Tumblr

Tags: tumblr

I want to stop the default Tumblr "(Source: _____ )" from displaying at the bottom of my posts. I've tried inserting the code and the jQuery from [this tread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643215/how-to-remove-the-source-from-this-tumblr-theme), but it doesn't work.

I can hide it using a bunch of CSS codes, but I want a more stable way to hide them. Anyone know how? I contacted Tumblr, but they are no help.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don’t remove it from your theme (i.e., directly in the template code)?

Comment: The JavaScript workaround is **not good** at all, remove the source blocks from your them. I don't see any obligation to keep them (unless you want to hide them for particular posts)

Comment: I've tried removing the source block from my theme, but all of the posts that have a source link attached to them still show source at the bottom. I've developed the theme from scratch myself, so I'm using the CSS workaround. There doesn't seem to be another option.

Comment: That means the source text is in the post body itself. Why remove the source though? Attribution is important.

Comment: My Tumblr page is setup like a news website. The top of each post has the article title, date and by _________. The by part is where I have the source block. That I'd the part I want to keep. The part I don't want is the extra (Source: ______) that Tumblr adds to the bottom of each post. It is added in a separate paragraph element that has no class or ID for CSS styling. That's why it's so hard to remove it. I have setup CSS rules that will hide that paragraph element using parent and sibling styling selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way it works:

If you have something like (or the [source](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#content-sources) image inside the link);

`{block:ContentSource}
    <a class="post_source" href="{SourceURL}" title="Source: {SourceTitle}" target="_blank"> Source </a>
{/block:ContentSource}`

You can show the source anywhere you want, however you want, and you can hide it by, well CSS; `.post_source { display: none }`.

If you do not have something like above, Tumblr will show the source link (like `(Source: Source Title)`), inside of the post (below everything else), in some cases, it is not always in your control.

If this does not work, most probably there is something else that is breaking or overriding your rules. Check and let me know. There are always options.

**Update:**

If you do see the "Source" two times, that is where you put it and the one Tumblr appends under some posts, I am pretty sure something else is wrong somewhere, I can not imagine what, since you did not post any codes.

 You can use JavaScript to hide it (If it seems better to you than your HTML and CSS solution. I am not sure how you are doing it, I do not see a better solution than using JavaScript to check the contents inside.):

In the code used, I assumed you have all your captions, text post body etc inside an element with class `.text`. Change it to your selector.

```
var elem = document.querySelectorAll(".text"), elemCont, i;
for (i = 0; i < elem.length; i += 1) { 
    elemCont = elem[i].lastElementChild.innerHTML.toLowerCase();
    if (elemCont.indexOf("(source:") === 0) {
        elem[i].lastElementChild.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

What I believe; Do not use any code you do not understand.
So explaining (in case something does not look familiar to you):

- The variable `elem` selects all the element with the class `.text`.
- The `for loop` loops over all the selected element one after another till we get to the last element.
- The variable `elemCont` is equal to; the "Inner HTML", in lowercase (to avoid conflicts when matching later) of the "last child (that is an element)", of the selected element `.text`.
- Here [i] is the `index` (0 or 1 or 2...). Selects one element at a time.
- Then with an `if` statement the algorithm checks if the `elemCont` (contents inside the selected element's last child, or paragraph in this case) starts with `(source:`. If true, the algorithm sets the last child of the selected element's style to `display: "none"`.
- Voilà now they are all hidden.

Comment: I already have the above source code in my theme, but I'm still receiving the default source line added to the bottom of my posts. I can't see anything that would be conflicting with the source block.

Comment: When you have something like I mentioned, visible (make it visible if not), you see both (this and the `(Source: Source Title)`)?